# Xcode fail to build test in Swift because of the error Cannot find UIImage in scope

Tags: xcode, testing

I was trying to run a test in Xcode.

I got the following errors when I try to run one of my tests

Cannot find UIImage in scope

Cannot find 'UIImageJPEGRepresentation' in scope

This is part of my code that compiler is complaining in my class ResMarcasModel:

```
class ResMarcasModel {

// more code....

private init(idResenha: Int, id: Int, parte: String, nomeImg: String, descricao: String ) {
    self.idResenha = idResenha
    self.id = id
    self.parte = parte
    self.eixoX = 0
    self.eixoY = 0
    self.nomeImg = nomeImg
    self.widthImg = String( ResMarcasModel.getImageWidthAndWeight(imageNameString: nomeImg).width )
    self.heightImg = String( ResMarcasModel.getImageWidthAndWeight(imageNameString: nomeImg).height )
    self.descricao = descricao
    self.tag = String(id)
    self.rotateX = 0
    self.rotateY = 0
    self.tipo = "V"
    self.fixa = "S"
    self.sobrepoe = "N"
    self.statusEnviada = "N"
}

static func encodeImageAsBase64String(image:UIImage) -> String {
    //let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"imageNameHere")!
    //let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
    let imageData:Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1)!
    let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
    return strBase64
}

// more code....

}
```

Does my INIT method need to be rewritten? How can I fix that?

Comment: UIImage exists only if you import UIKit. (Just like anything that starts with UI.) Did you import it?

Comment: Every IDE/language can suggest imports but I don't see it in XCode :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple fix. I just forget to import UIKit.
Thanks to @matt for pointing out the fix for the problem.